# Finding a sum from based off value from adjacent column

Tags: excel, logic, excel-2010

Bit of a silly question, but i've got a small logic problem with an excel formula

If ive got 2 rows of various values, such that it looks like:

```
A    B
1   101
2   150
3   200
4   50
5   70
6   20
```

How do I find the sum of all values under 'B' that are adjacent to a value in 'A' that is greater than 3?
So essentially it would add up only 50, 70 and 20, as those are adjacent to 4, 5 and 6.
Currently I've got:

```
=SUMIF(H5:H11,INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH("<3",A1:A6,-1),B1:6))
```

Naturally this is going to be used with a much larger data set, of a few thousand values - so any advice would be incredibly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A6,">3",B1:B6)
```

Returns 140